# Randomly select and move 500 directories/folders from a folder to another?

Tags: linux

I want to move/copy 500 folders from one directory to another. Here, I am not choosing the files randomly but directories/folders.

I used the following command to do it, but i am able to mv only a few folders and not 500 folders are moved. Any suggestions on the following command?

```
ls | shuf -n 500 | xargs -i mv {} /path-folder/
```

Comment: I think you should write a bash script for that if you can give more info I can help you

Comment: Does the directory where you run this contain sub-directories **and** files -- in which case files are being moved unintentionally as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find -type d` to select directories, `shuf` to randomize the order, and `head -n 500` to select 500 random directories:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | shuf | head -n 500 | xargs -I{} mv {} dest_dir/
```

See also [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) manual for more details.

Comment: Note: `mindepth`/`maxdepth` options should be specified *first*

Comment: Thank you for your reply!. Here suppose if i want copy these folders instead of moving it. Can i use it like this:                                                                                                      
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | shuf | head -n 500 | xargs cp -r {} dest_dir/

Comment: Just to update the above solution. This works better without error:  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | shuf | head -n 500 | xargs -I {} mv {} dest_dir/